# javascript, ajax, table, colour

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wrote a bit of script to change the coulor of text on table rows based on a value. I am quite new to this so having some syntax issues. Can you see anything wrong with this:

```
 function ReturnValuesAsColor(Eval(online), Eval(mobile), Eval(server_proc)) {
    if  (online == -1){
        return "online";
    }else if (mobile == -1) {
        return "mobile";
    }else if (server_proc == -1){
        return "server_proc";
    }else 
        return;
    }};
```

thank you

Comment: You missed a `{` after the `else` case. and remove evals.

Comment: Could be a typo, but you are missing a `{` after the else i.e. `else { return ;}`

Comment: yep thank you, that has fixed it.

i cant up vote either of your comments but thank you both

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ReturnValuesAsColor
> ```

It is convention to start a function name with a capital letter only if it is a constructor function, which this is not.

> ```
> (Eval(online), Eval(mobile), Eval(server_proc))
> ```

Eval() is nonsense. Just put the variable names when you define your arguments.

```
function returnValuesAsColor(online, mobile, server_proc)
```